# What's the most efficient way to get the horizontal average in a MySQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql, average

I have the following MySQL-table

```
Id  |  One  |  Two  |  Three
----------------------------
1   |  10   |  30   |  20
2   |  50   |  60   |  20
3   |  60   |  NULL |  40
```

**Edit:** Of course the table doesn't need to be NULL by default, but I don't want it to affect the average (so the average is calculated as 50 and not 33,33).

I want that to look like this, with a MySQL query:

```
Id | Average
------------
1  | 20
2  | 43,33
3  | 50
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select id, (ifnull(one,0) + ifnull(two,0) + ifnull(three,0))/
  ((one is not null) + (two is not null) + (three is not null)) as average from table
```

Comment: Looks good but watch out for divide by zero if all 3 are null.

Comment: Revised my comment. `select 0/0;` actually returns `NULL`. I had no idea ... this answer is perfect

Answer (score 3):

The obvious option below would have worked if you had no NULL values:

```
SELECT ((col_1 + col_2 + col_3) / 3) AS Average FROM table;
```

However, as [jxac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/262976/jxac) suggested in another answer, you would have to do it as follows:

```
SELECT id, (ifnull(col_1, 0) + ifnull(col_2, 0) + ifnull(col_3, 0)) /
  ((col_1 is not null) + (col_2 is not null) + (col_3 is not null)) as Average 
FROM
    table;
```

If all the values of each column were to be NULL, the division by zero would return NULL for that row.

Comment: @Eikern: Is there any reason why this is not appropriate for your problem?

Comment: this wouldn't work in the third row: `SELECT 60 + NULL + 40` returns `NULL`. And the result would be wrong too: The average of 60 and 50 is 50, as in the example, your query would return 33.3 (if it wouldn't return `NULL` obviously)

Comment: @Cassy: Thanks for that. Didn't notice the NULL value. Edited my answer to include jxac's alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
  SELECT a.id,
         AVG(a.val) AS average
    FROM (SELECT x.id,
                 x.one AS val
            FROM TABLE x
          UNION ALL
          SELECT y.id,
                 y.two AS val
            FROM TABLE y
          UNION ALL
          SELECT z.id,
                 z.three AS val
            FROM TABLE z) a
GROUP BY a.id
```

### Reference:

- [AVG](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)